# Listeners in TabHost and TabActivity issue

Tags: android, listener, android-tabhost

I have a TabHost with tab activities.
From the TabHost I use startActivityForResult.
in the onActivityResult function i use sendBroadcast.

The listener is in one Tab activity.
I init the listener as below:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();

    if( mIsListenerRegistered == false )
    {
        registerReceiver( mListener, new IntentFilter("org.myApp.NotifyUserRatingChanged") );
        mIsListenerRegistered = true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();

    if( mIsListenerRegistered ) 
    {
        unregisterReceiver( mListener );
        mIsListenerRegistered = false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that because I use in the TabHost startActivitForResult then the onPause is called and the received is being unregistered.
Now the onActivityResult is called before the onResume (of the tab) is called. So what happens is that I send the broadcast before the listener is re-registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously this will not work because you have not register a receiver yet

Why you don't try to register receiver in the `onCreate()` method and
unregister in the `onDestroy()` method.

Activity Lifecycle is between `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()`.